# TTYs show some kind of white noise

Tags: graphics, tty

What am I supposed to do with this? I don't even know how to Google it, let alone how to accurately describe or fix it:

[image: This kind of white noise]

Comment: That's because you're using the Nvidia proprietary driver: [Why are my virtual consoles completely blank?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/157111). I don't know of any fix though.